# how to create blob url for a locally hosted video?

Tags: javascript, blob

I have hosted a video at my localhost

```
 'localhost:3000/videos/a1.m4'
```

how can i convert it to blob url  below is my code which is not working

```
 let URL = window.URL
 let blob = new Blob(['localhost:3000/videos/a1.m4'], {type : 'video/mp4'}); 
 let src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

<video width="320" height="240" controls>
                    <source src={src} type="video/mp4"/>

</video>
```

Comment: Blob doesn't expect a URL to a resource, it expects the actual raw data of the resource. Read up on it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

Comment: Besides, why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Kaiido i saw it on youtube they use blob:url for video i'm very keen to know how to achieve it

Comment: YT uses the [MediaSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource) API, but except if you also have the code to provide varying quality you don't need it.